# How to use a typeclass into a polymorphic data type?

Tags: haskell

I defined the following data type:

```
type MySet a = (a -> Bool)
```

I want to use it to define a set of functions that have the following property: 
For all f in func3, f 3 == 2.

```
func3 :: MySet (Eq a => a -> a)
func3 = (\x -> (x 3) == 2)
```

The following error arises:

```
Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: Eq a => a -> a
Perhaps you intended to use -XLiberalTypeSynonyms
In the type signature for `func3': func3 :: MySet (Eq a => a -> a)
```

If I don't use the Eq typeclass, I get this error instead:

```
No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
Possible fix:
  add (Eq a) to the context of
  the type signature for func3 :: MySet (a -> a)
```

Comment: Try this `func3 :: (Num a, Eq a) => MySet (a -> a)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often the first step to working out a problem involving type synonyms (things that look like `type ... = ...`) is to go through manually replacing the synonym (the left hand side of the `type` expression) with its expansion (the right hand side). So:

```
func3 :: MySet (Eq a => a -> a)
```

becomes:

```
func4 :: (Eq a => a -> a) -> Bool
```

Now GHC gives us a more helpful error:

```
Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: Eq a => a -> a
Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or Rank2Types
In an expression type signature: (Eq a => a -> a) -> Bool
```

`RankNTypes` is a fun extension, but it's not very helpful here. (I'll explain in a moment).

As n.m. pointed out, what you probably want to do is just move the constraints out of the parentheses:

```
func5 :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> Bool
```

And then GHC lets you know you also need `Num`. Other than that, though, we have a totally ordinary-looking type signature: a constraint before the `=>`, then regular type variables and a specific type. This is good; we generally want the types as straightforward as possible (but not more so).

But let's back up and examine two things: type synonyms and `RankNTypes`.

First, you called `MySet` a "data type." That's kind of a dangerous way to think of it. It's actually a *type synonym*, which means just what it sounds like: `MySet (a -> a)` and `(a -> a) -> Bool` are literally synonymous; they mean the same thing. Contrast something like `data MySetD a = MySetD (a -> Bool)`. There, `MySetD` is actually an honest-to-God data type that *cannot* be substituted, willy-nilly, for `(a -> Bool)` and vice-versa.

Second: What's up with `RankNTypes`? If we turn that extension on, we could write this:

```
funcRN :: (forall a. (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a) -> Bool
funcRN = (\x -> (x 3) == 2)
```

And it does what you want with things like `funcRN ((+) 1)`. But what about this?

```
g :: Int -> Int
g x = x - 1

funcRN g
```

This doesn't work. `funcRN` requires as its argument a function that can take *any* type `a` such that `a` is an instance of `Eq` and `Num`. That's what the `forall a. (Eq a, Num a) =>` bit means. Since `g` only works with *one* type, `Int`, it's unacceptable to `funcRN`'s type signature.